# stored procedure in sql used in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have used following stored procedure in sql:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_Member_Org_OnGoingJobs]
(
    @idUser varchar(50)

)
as
begin
declare @qry as varchar(max)
set @qry='select J.idJob,j.DateAdded,j.OpenedByWho,j.JobAddress ,j.final,j.idOrg,j.note
                              from Job J 
                              inner join Users U on
                              U.idOrg=J.idOrg
                              where U.IdUser='+ @idUser+ '
                              and ISNULL(j.Final,'')='' 
                              order by idJob'


  execute(@qry)
end
GO
```

This stored procedure is formed sucessfully in sql.

But, When i tried to use them through asp.net c#, It gives me error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
```

Everything seems correct.

Please tell me where i am making mistake??

Edit:

```
private void BindOnGoingJobs()
    {
        string sqlOnGoingJobs = "usp_Member_Org_OnGoingJobs";

        DataTable dtJobList = new DataTable();
        ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();

        paramList.Add(new ParamData("@idUser", Convert.ToString(Session["idUser"])));
        dtJobList = obj.ExecuteProcedureAndGetDataTable(sqlOnGoingJobs, paramList);
        grdOnGoingJobs.DataSource = dtJobList;
        grdOnGoingJobs.DataBind();

        paramList.Clear();
    }

 public DataTable ExecuteProcedureAndGetDataTable(string procedureName, ArrayList Parameters)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                foreach (ParamData p in Parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.pName, p.pValue);
                }
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                con.Close();
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Steve sir i added the functions which calls this stored procedures... Using them to bind grid

Comment: As a side note, any particular reason you are using dynamic sql within your stored proc?  Dynamic sql looks totally unnecessary for what you are doing, and in fact opens you up to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double your single quotes around the ISNULL check

```
set @qry='select J.idJob,j.DateAdded,j.OpenedByWho,j.JobAddress ,j.final,j.idOrg,j.note
                          from Job J 
                          inner join Users U on
                          U.idOrg=J.idOrg
                          where U.IdUser='+ @idUser+ '
                          and ISNULL(j.Final,'''')='''' 
                          order by idJob'
```

Comment: you need to do the same with `idUser` check too like this `where U.IdUser='''+ @idUser+ '''`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotation mark by placing quotes 2 times like this.

> `and ISNULL(j.Final,'''')=''''`

Check this blog post http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the table alias in order by, I guess should solve the issue

order by J.idJob